# How do I fix a Null reference exception in Visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I don't know why this keeps happening but when ever I try to imput changes to the file nothing will happen. I added an exception to see if it doesn't happen but it keeps happening. Please help q.q

```
Private Sub subBut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles         subBut.Click
    If gradeBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
        Dim grade As String = Convert.ToInt32(gradeBox.Text)
            If grade > 0 Then
             ' imputs grade to file
            writer.WriteLine(grade) ' error 
            Else
            Application.Exit()
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict` - this makes no sense at all: `Dim grade As String = Convert.ToInt32(gradeBox.Text)`.. What is `writer` and where did it come from?

Comment: You probably forgot the `New` keyword when creating your `writer` variable.